# Lubuntu installation

Tags: lubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu, and so far I love it. I've done a couple of installs of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on some old computers from a LiveCD a coworker gave me. I'm now interested in upgrading my network, including a Gateway LT4010u netbook with Intel Atom N2600 processor and 4GB of RAM, and 320GB Hard drive. I would like to install Lubuntu 14.04 LTS on this machine. My question is:

Is it possible to install the 64-bit Intel/AMD64 version, or is the Atom REALLY a 32-bit processor?

I intend to make a bootable USB stick for the install.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

P.S. No hurry. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS works just fine for now. I wonder why it only sees 2.91 GB of the 4 GB memory stick, though....

Comment: What is the output of the following when executed on a terminal: `free -m | grep Mem: | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'`? (Open a terminal using Ctrl + Alt + t)

Comment: 3018. I installed 4 GB of ram recently. I'm saving up for a hybrid drive. Can't really afford an SSD. Gotta feed my cat...

Answer (score 0):

To check what processor architecture you have you can use the following command:

```
uname -p
```

You should be able to install the 64-bit version of Lubuntu if your processor is *x86_64* or 64-bit.

The reason for why the USB stick is only shown as 2.91GB can be for multiple reasons but it's probably related to formatting, that if it is in face 4GB.

Comment: Would that report x86_64 for a 64-bit chip on a board that only supported 32-bit use? Some systems at the time were like that.

Comment: 32-bit iso installed and is working great! Love Lubuntu! perfect for a netbook.Thanks!

Comment: BTW, Ubuntu 12.04 was reporting 2.91 GB of ram, and I had just installed a 4GB ram module. Maybe it was reporting free ram?

Answer (score 0):

> All Atom processors implement the x86 (IA-32) instruction set; however, support for the Intel 64 instruction set was not added until the desktop Diamondville and desktop and mobile Pineview cores. - Wikipedia

If the notebook was produced before 2008 maybe its really 32bit (x86).

BUT if you want to make sure that your processor is 64bit or really 32bit, you can just burn 2 ISO versions of Lubuntu/Ubuntu.

When you boot from LiveCD with the wrong version for the system architecture, will display a simple message saying that you need, for example, **i634 software**
I saw this message when i try to boot 64bit Ubuntu LiveCD with an old Celeron (2004) Notebook. Just shut-down and insert the right CD/Usb.

Comment: Hi Fernando. Jobin suggested runnung "uname -p" in the terminal, which returned "i686". I did a search and found that it's a 32-bit architecure, so I downloaded and installed the 32-bit iso, and it works beautifully! Thanks for responding.